# AngularJS - rangy import - Rangy is not supported in this environment. Reason: No body element found

Tags: angularjs, rangy

I will use this inline text editor

[AngularJS inline text editor](https://github.com/Blitzen/angular-inline-text-editor)

therefore I included the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='assets/bower_components/angular-text/dist/rangy-core.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='assets/bower_components/angular-text/dist/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='assets/bower_components/angular-text/dist/rangy-classapplier.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='assets/bower_components/angular-text/dist/ite.js'></script>
```

in my index.html in the head tag but I get the following browser console output:

```
Rangy is not supported in this environment. Reason: No body element found
```

Does anyone know why?

**[EDIT]**
The problem is that in rangy-core there is an access to body, but body is still null:

```
var body = getBody(document);
    if (!body || body.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "body") {
        fail("No body element found");
        return;
    }
```

I have included the javascript files in  tag and I also tried to include it inside body tag but with no success.